# Cannot hide CakePHP DebugKit Toolbar

Tags: php, debugging, cakephp, firefox

since today I cannot hide the debugkit toolbar in CakePHP. I mean if I click on the cake icon the toolbar doesn't roll to right.

I know that I can disable it by setting Debug to 0. But I need debug output. The rolled out toolbar hides the code lines of my debug output. I also don't want to change the css settings of this toolbar, because i am working in a shared project and don't want the other developers to have this changed.

It is a local problem. I alredy deleted the cake cache and I am running my browser in private mode. The bar always apears completely. Not only the cake icon is displayed, all the debug links are displayed, too. I don't know why. It is magical but since today just clicking the cake icon doesn't hide the bar. But why???

Regards

Comment: please check firebug may be js has broken

Comment: It is always open if you output debug code before <html> tag. I bet you have some debug in beforeFilter or similar, right? about the problems with hiding it, it should be some javascript issue as @Moyed mentioned

Comment: Hey, thank you both. You helped me solved the problem. Firebug is great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Try to comment or remove  //'DebugKit.Toolbar', from your AppController
- In you case try to comment imported css (All other css) from the layout. Because other style might broken the DebugKit.Toolbar.
- Using ctrl+shift+i in your browser (inspect element -> console) to see if in JS is broken.
- Some cases also said that If your database is not properly configured you will have problem with DebugKit.Toolbar

Comment: No, I don't want to hide it completely. I want to hide the links and just see the Cake-Picture so that by clicking on the Cake-Picture I see the links again.

Comment: I assume you have problem with your css document. because DebugKit.Toolbar works like the way you are saying. by clicking on cake picture buttons appears otherwise you are able to see only cake  picture.

Answer (score 1):

to remove the debug kit icon (so toolbar element in your html) just go to "app.php" and set "debug => false"

Answer (score 1):

in `config\bootstrap.php` the following line

```
if (Configure::read('debug')) { Plugin::load('DebugKit', ['bootstrap' => true]); }
```

will become

```
if (Configure::read('debug')) { Plugin::load('DebugKit', ['bootstrap' => false]); }
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to vendor/cakephp/debug_kit/webroot/js
Then just disable everything in function onReady.

Ex:

```
var onReady = function() {
    /* if (!win.__debug_kit_id) {
        return;
    }
    var body = doc.body;
    iframe = doc.createElement('iframe');
    iframe.setAttribute('style', 'position: fixed; bottom: 0; right: 0; border: 0; outline: 0; overflow: hidden; z-index: 99999;');
    iframe.height = 40;
    iframe.width = 40;
    iframe.src = __debug_kit_base_url + 'debug_kit/toolbar/' + __debug_kit_id;

    body.appendChild(iframe);

    bodyOverflow = body.style.overflow;

    window.addEventListener('message', onMessage, false); */
};
```

Answer (score 0):

app.php

one of the first lines

```
  'debug' => filter_var(env('DEBUG', true), FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN),
```

change this ----------------------------------------^

```
  'debug' => filter_var(env('DEBUG', false), FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN),
```

Answer (score 0):

go to **htdocs/my_app_name/src/Application.php**
comment this line

```
if (Configure::read('debug')) {
        // $this->addPlugin('DebugKit');
     }
```

your code

```
  if (Configure::read('debug')) {
            // $this->addPlugin('DebugKit');
         }
```

reload page